# Conversion of time to seconds

Tags: vb.net

I have this conversion issue.

I have a stopwatch which counts down. Then displays it on a label so it shows like this "15:00:00" on a label(label1) counting down.

I have another time which loop every 10 seconds to lap the stopwatch and save the lapped time to another label(label2)

So how did I get 15:00:00?

I have 3 textboxes in my form, 1st is for hours, 2nd for minutes and third for sec.
If I input 15 on hours, and 00 on minutes and seconds and hit button1, it automatically converts 15hours(15:00:00) to seconds which is saved in my database so instead of saving 15:00:00 it saves the TotalSeconds which is 54000 Seconds.

When my stopwatch starts, it gets the 54000 from database and again converts it to 15:00:00 that is displayed in label1.

Can I convert lapped time on label2("13:00:00") to seconds which will display the converted value yet to another label(which is now label3).?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Timers

Public Class ClientDashboard

Dim StopWatch As New Stopwatch
Dim CountDown As TimeSpan
Dim IsRunning As Boolean = False
Private Shared timer As System.Timers.Timer

Private Sub ClientDashboard_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Sets dashboard to right
    Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(317, 900)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 317
    y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
    Me.Location = New Point(x, y)

    'get time of user
    cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Call conDB()
    cn.Open()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open("select * from tb_registration where=st_acc_number= '" & id_lbl.Text & "'", cn, 0, 3)
    iduser_lbl.Text = "'" & rs("st_name").Value & "'""'" & rs("st_lname").Value & "'"
    UserTotal.Text = rs("st_totaltimeleft").Value

    'Start stopwatch
    StopWatch.Start()
    synchroUpdate.Enabled = True
    synchroUpdate.Start()
    Dim numSecs As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(UserTotal.Text, numSecs)
    CountDown = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(numSecs)

End Sub

Private Sub synchro_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles synchro.Tick


End Sub

'--------------------->>>> Methord 2 <<<<----------------------
Private Sub DispElaps(ByVal ts As TimeSpan, ByVal lbl As Label)
    lbl.Text = String.Format("{0:00}    :    {1:00}    :    {2:00}", _
                             Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), _
                             ts.Minutes, _
                             ts.Seconds, _
                             ts.Milliseconds)
End Sub

Private Sub synchroUpdate_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles synchroUpdate.Tick
    synchroUpdate.Interval = 100
    'If countDown > stpw.Elapsed Then
    Dim elaps As TimeSpan = CountDown - StopWatch.Elapsed
    DispElaps(elaps, TimerOutput)
    'Else
    'End If
End Sub

Private Sub DoEvent()
    timer = New System.Timers.Timer(5000)
    AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf AC
    timer.AutoReset = True
    timer.Enabled = True
End Sub
'Address of event
Private Sub SaveEvent2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    AutoUpdate_Button.PerformClick()
End Sub
'Event Handler
Private Sub AC()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf AC))
    Else
        Me.AutoUpdate_Button.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub logoutBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles logoutBTN.Click

End Sub

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm new at this forum, be gentle with me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to use good names for labels, but your question has not been updated to correspond.

Nevertheless, can you just use `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` similar to where where you're already using `TimeSpan.TotalHours`?

Comment: I've came up this code below and added it in the lap event

    Private Sub totalsec(ByVal fs As TimeSpan, ByVal lbl2 As Label)
        lbl2.Text = TimeSpan.Parse(Label5.Text).TotalSeconds
    End Sub